SwiftUI frame height not being updated with ActiveLabel
I have a swiftUI view using UIViewRepresentable to show an ActiveLabel I have a .frame() modifier on that ActiveLabel which has a height which is reflected by a @State variable. When this height is updated the frame height does not always seem to update. Am I doing anything obvious wrong.
Here is a simplified version of my setup, let me know if if it would be usefl to include more of my solution.
let text:String
let mentions: [String: String]
let lineLimit:Int?
@State private var height: CGFloat = .zero


var body: some View {
    ActiveLabelWrapper(
        text: text,
        lineLimit: lineLimit,
        height: $height,
        handleHashtagTap: {hashtag in print(hashtag)},
        handleMentionTap: {username in print(username)}
    ).frame(minHeight: height)
}

Here is the ActiveLabelWrapper:
enter cstruct ActiveLabelWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
let text: String
let lineLimit: Int?
@Binding var height: CGFloat
let handleHashtagTap: (String) -> Void
let handleMentionTap: (String) -> Void

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ActiveLabel {
    let label = ActiveLabel()
    label.enabledTypes = [.mention, .hashtag]
    label.text = text

    ...

    label.numberOfLines = lineLimit ?? 0
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    return label
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: ActiveLabel, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = text
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        height = uiView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: uiView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
    }
}

This code seems to work most of the time when using the ios simulator (not all the time) but when I open the app on my physical device the height is not updated once the ActiveLabel text is created, instead it shows only a single line of text rather than all of the lines.
For some more context, the reason I believe the problem lies within the frame height not updating is that I have confirmed the ui.sizeThatFits(...) is returning the correct value. And even if I manually update the size with an .onAppear() or .task() the frame height never changes.
What am I missing? I have tried a lot and nothing has worked, so any help is appreciated.

Why minHeight? SwiftUI has every right to not do anything when the min height decreases.

The min height will always increase though, it starts as .zero. I have also tried with just "height" but I get the same issue
